# How to pass list from controller to javascript function in asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have this query in the controller:

```
 DataClasses1DataContext behzad = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            var query = (from p in behzad.ImagePaths
                         select new
                         {
                             p.name
                         }).ToList();
            ViewBag.movies = query;


            return View();
```

and write this java script code in view page:

```
function behi() {
        @{
            var behzad = ViewBag.movies;
        }

        alert('@(behzad)');


    }
```

that java script code show me this:
[image]

how can i write java script code for show controller query result?thanks all.

Comment: `var behzad = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.movies)); alert(behzad);`  (and not wrapped in `@{ ... }`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serialize it. The below code use Newtonsoft's Json serializer to do so.

```
var movies = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.movies));
```

Now the `movies` variable will be an array of items, each with a `name` property.

Answer (score 0):

Serialize return object to json like below, and use it in the javascript.
JavaScriptSerializer class is in System.Web.Script.Serialization package.
Hope this helps.

```
DataClasses1DataContext behzad = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            var query = (from p in behzad.ImagePaths
                         select new
                         {
                             p.name
                         }).ToList();
            ViewBag.movies = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(query);
            return View();
```

Comment: that's work,but java script alert show me this:[{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;http://s2.picofile.com/file/7783181933/Demo_Rehlat_Imam_Khomeini.jpg                                &quot;},{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;http://farsi.rouhollah.ir/image/imam.jpg                                                            &quot;}] that is &quot.